# java. maven. Идея не подхватывает новый модуль

Tags: java, maven, apache-modules

Импортировал в идею maven проект все открылось хорошо. Начал добавлять третий модуль, не подхватывает. Помогите найти ошибку в pom.xml она явно там.

Это корневой:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.pravvich</groupId>
    <artifactId>junior</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <modules>
        <module>chapter_001</module>
        <module>chapter_002</module>
        <module>chapter_003</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Это вложенный в него как раз chapter_003

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.pravvich</groupId>
    <artifactId>chapter_003</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <modules>
        <module>lesson_1</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Ну и последний который должен собираться в jar:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.pravvich</groupId>
    <artifactId>lesson_1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>



<properties>    
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>                  
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    </properties>   

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>ru.pravvich</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Ошибку покажите.

Comment: Я создавал уже модуль с именем chapter_003 и удалил хотел пересоздать и теперь у меня не подхватывается содержимое, тоесть я не могу создать в нем не пакет не класс только простую директорию, хотя сам он горит черным
chapter_003 в вкладке Maven Progects есть с пометкой (root)

Comment: Сделайте Clean, затем Install. Покажите Error какой пишет.

Comment: так вот в том то и дело что через терминал все билдится а идея не подхватывает вот ссылка на скрин http://s61.radikal.ru/i174/1611/9a/11a9ec5c03ad.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас неправильно настроен pom.xml в модуле chapter_003, должен быть так:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.pravvich</groupId>
    <artifactId>chapter_003</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>ru.pravvich</groupId>
        <artifactId>junior</artifactId>            
        <version>1.0</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <build>
    <finalName>chapter_003</finalName>        
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>            
    </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

После этого можете собирать jar файл в консоли командой `mvn clean install`. Также этот модуль будет автоматически включен при сборке корневого проекта